# React Controlled Forms breaks with onChange function

Tags: reactjs, forms, onchange

I have a form, whith a default value that can be changed. When a change happens, my form should update the state, as well as dispatching an event (and more, but I've left it out here). Consider this code:

```
 const onFormChangeTest = (event) => {
  setName(event.target.value);
  eventDispatch({type: ACTION.TOGGLE_SAVE_BTN, payload: false});
};

return (
  <div className={"updateContainer"}>
    <form>
      <input
        name="namebox"
        id="currentName"
        onChange={onFormChangeTest}
        value={name}
      />
 </div>
```

the code above fails to update the value in the form. Or rather, the input `namebox` gets reset to the initial value as soon as I'm not typing.

If, on the other hand, I remove the `eventDispatch` line from the `onFromChangeTest` function, then it works (but I don't get to fire my dispatcher):

```
 const onFormChangeTest = (event) => {
  setName(event.target.value);
};

return (
  <div className={"updateContainer"}>
    <form>
      <input
        name="namebox"
        id="currentName"
        onChange={onFormChangeTest}
        value={name}
      />
 </div>
```

Form works, but I can only call useState and nothing else:
Can I only do one thing in `onChange`?

EDIT: the reducer code looks like this:

```
export const initialState = {
  saveChangesBtn: true,
};
export const ACTION = {
  TOGGLE_SAVE_BTN: "toggle-save-button",
};
export const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    ... (some other states) ...
    case ACTION.TOGGLE_SAVE_BTN:
      return { ...state, saveChangesBtn: action.payload };
  }
};
```

Comment: Didn't find any issue with the current code. what happens after this evenDispatch ? show us that code. are you using that dispatched value back in component ?

Comment: Hello @sojin
I'm re-rendering the state of a button. The state of the button is updated with the dispatched event. I have added the reducer code in the original post.

Comment: My guess is that dispatching the event is doing something that causes the form to re-mount, so it loses its state.

Comment: Re mounting must be the issue here. please post your working code in `codesandbox` or any similar. and share the link

Comment: Hello again. Thanks for your input!
I think you are right about the remounting. I solved it by first triggering the `onFormChangeTest()` in the `onBlur()`-event. Not ideal, but it works for the use case I'm looking to solve.